# Label direction check

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, direction

I want to visualize direction of river's course by an arrow placed next to the river's name label.
I have an idea to place the blue arrow as a text in front of my label or at the end of my label, but the problem is with the qgis label engine. Depending on vector rotation label puts along or across the vector direction. Can I check somehow if label is placed along or across the vector direction? I would prefer the solution by Expression or maybe you have any better ideas how to visualize that...

Expected result below: (I marked the river's course (which equals vector direction) with the red arrow):
[image]

Comment: Can you please specify which version of QGIS are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve your problem you have two different options.

**Solution 1 by default option**

QGIS, at least from the 3.10 (not sure about previous versions), offers the opportunity to add this arrow symbol to the label by default using one of the Labels options.

In *Layout Manager > Labels*  in the *Formatting page*, active the option `Line direction symbol` and, here, use the arrow symbols (you can copy them from the System Character Map).

This will suit your request. But, as discussed in the comments, this solution turn off the possibility to activate the useful option *Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels* and seem to be not compatible with the *Placement* Curved or Horizontal.

[image]

**Solution 2 by expression (recommended)**

You can achieve the same result using an expression that calculates the direction of the line to populate your label.

This is the expression

```
with_variable('direction',
    angle_at_vertex ($geometry, if( num_points( $geometry) >1, num_points( $geometry)/2, 1)),
        case 
        when @direction < 179 then 'label →'
        when @direction > 180 and  @direction < 360 then '← label'
        end
)
```

This solution is recommended because keep active and selectable the option *Merge connected lines to avoid the duplicate labels* and works with all the *Placement* options.

The `if` option in the expression permits to calculate the direction on the middle of a line with several nodes and avoid to misinterpreted a line that has an irregular proceeding.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about that option in qgis. :)

Comment: I've noticed that enabling option "Line direction symbol" turns off an option "Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels" from Rendering page. Is there any way to keep that option/result on?

Comment: I have realised. It could be a problem. Unfortunately, I can't see any solution using only the default options. If this is for you a mandatory point, a label by expression would be an alternative solution.

Comment: what expression you mean?

Comment: I mean an expression that can calculate the direction  of the line and change the label according with that. I can Tey to work on it and add to the answer as second solution.

Comment: Would be cool, thanks in advance. I've noticed one more thing. On the Placement page is an option Placement: Parallel, Curved and Horizontal . When I set Curved or Horizontal my arrows hide. Is this a bug or correct behavior?

Comment: Answer updated. Solution 2 should solve all your problems with default options.

Comment: There is one problem, basically your solution 2 is okay, but rivers in my data set are very curved and have many vertexes (sometimes over 100 per 1 line). Calculating angle of middle vertex doesn't always mean, that whole line would have the same angle. Maybe its possible to get the closest vertex of that place where label is going to place...